# How to current snapshot of MySQL Table and store it into CSV file(after creating it)?

Tags: php, csv

I have large database table, approximately 5GB, now I wan to getCurrentSnapshot of Database using `"Select * from MyTableName"`, am using `PDO` in `PHP` to interact with Database. So preparing a query and then executing it

```
        // Execute the prepared query
        $result->execute();
        $resultCollection = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

is not an efficient way as lots of memory is being user for storing into the associative array data which is approximately, `5GB`.

My final goal is to collect data returned by `Select` query into an CSV file and put CSV file at an FTP Location from where Client can get it.

Other Option I thought was to do:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "c:/mydata.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
FROM my_table;
```

But I am not sure if this would work as I have cron that initiates the complete process and we do not have an csv file, so basically for this approach,

1. PHP Scripts will have to create an CSV file.
2. Do a Select query on the database.
3. Store the select query result into the CSV file.

What would be the best or efficient way to do this kind of task ?

Any Suggestions !!!

Comment: Do you have to use PHP? Can't you just dump a table using mysql from the command line or a shell script?

Comment: @Manos: I have to use PHP and I cannot directly dump a table using mysql from the command line or a shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the php function [fputcsv (see the PHP Manual)](http://de3.php.net/fputcsv) to write single lines of csv into a file. In order not to run into the memory problem, instead of fetching the whole result set at once, just select it and then iterate over the result:

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

$result->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // and here you can simply export every row to a file:
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: @Cassy: If am doing fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) for each time then will it now affect my database performance ?

Comment: The result set is cached in the database and every time you do a fetch() you only transfer the data from the database to your script. FetchAll() actually does the same thing implicitly. So no, the impact on the database is not so much different compared with fetchAll()

Comment: Seems to me you could probably cut down on the database cache usage by batching queries with `LIMIT`.  Just nest above code in another `while` loop.  Just depends whether you need to minimize memory usage over processing the queries.